# Alternative for Virtual DJ?

Tags: software-recommendation, alternative

I currently use Mixxx on my system, but I am so much accustomed to the features and shortcut keys in Virtual DJ. Does anybody know any good alternative for this software?

Answer (score 5):

[**Mixxx**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mixxx/)

It is a DJ application that easy to handle.

Can mix several file types.(.wave .ogg .mp3 etc.)

[image]

Can be installed with [**Software Center**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mixxx/) or with:

```
sudo apt-get install mixxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Mixxx is the most used. But feel free to check out these: 
[DJPlay](http://djplay.sourceforge.net/%20%22DJPlay) 
[XWax](http://xwax.org/)